# ExtJS ComboBox not displaying elements

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having trouble getting a ComboBox in ExtJS to display the dropdown items.  I originally was using an XmlStore to load the data dynamically, but to make sure that wasn't the problem, I took an existing ComboBox that uses a simple ArrayStore (and currently works elsewhere in my application) to see if it would work, still with no luck.

When using Chrome's developer tools, when I click on the ComboBox element, I get `ext-all-debug.js:41166 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getStyle' of undefined` and nothing shows up for a dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
EventForm = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            items: [
                {
                    layout: 'column',
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [
                        {
                            layout: 'form',
                            xtype: 'container',
                            columnWidth: 0.5,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    fieldLabel: 'My Combo Box'
                                    name: 'mycombobox',
                                    xtype: 'combo',
                                    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                        fields: ['size'],
                                        data: [
                                            ['50'],
                                            ['100'],
                                            ['150'],
                                            ['200']
                                        ]
                                    }),
                                    displayField: 'size',
                                    valueField: 'size',
                                    forceSelection: true,
                                    editable: false,
                                    triggerAction: 'all',
                                    mode: 'local',
                                    listWidth: 60,
                                    width: 60
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
                            // another column here similar to above
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, config);

        EventForm.superclass.constructor(config);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not calling the constructor of EventForm's superclass correctly. Change the last line of your constructor function to read:

```
EventForm.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
```

Comment: *bangs head against desk* - Thank you for noticing my stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` array must contain a list of objects, and the keys you provided by `fields` must be the keys your data refers to in those objects. The correct syntax for your `data` array could be:

```
data: [
    {'size':'50'},
    {'size':'100'},
    {'size':'150'},
    {'size':'200'}
]
```

(could be, because I have no chance right now to verify)

Comment: The ComboBox code that I have listed is actually from another part of my app and works without a problem.  In the end, I'll be using an XmlStore, but I figured to eliminate the errors that can occur with loading something remotely, I'd use an existing ComboBox that works in another part of my app.

Comment: all keys the same "size" won't work for sure... while { is object notation, array is []... array stores require about this format: data: [["50", "50"], ["100", "100"]]